# Python subprocess bash command with output file blocked

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, subprocess

I have the following code that runs `LM_CMD` program and writes the output into file `fp_arpa`. Right after that I have another function that reads and processes that file (`fp_arpa`). However, according to the function the file is empty, while in the file system it is not. I am guessing subprocess locks the file pointer until the whole Python program finishes (I might be wrong though). How can I avoid this problem?

```
base_cmd = '%s -lm %s' % (LM_CMD, fp_arpa)
subprocess.Popen([base_cmd], shell=True)
some_function_that_processes(fp_arpa)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`subprocess.Popen` returns immediately as soon as the process is started. It doesn't wait for the process to finish. Call [`subprocess.check_call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call) instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call([LM_CMD, '-lm', fp_arpa])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. For some reason I thought a program will wait until subprocess.Popen finishes.